# Upgrade/migrate from Laravel Mix to Vite

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-mix, laravel-vite

I use Laravel, and I upgraded Laravel to 10. Now, I want to replace Webpack with Vite, too. I do formal steps, and I stick to one step. In my case, my Webpack config is like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix
.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/tmp/app.js').vue()
.scripts([
    'public/tmp/app.js',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/vendors/js/extensions/dropzone.min.js',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/datatables.min.js',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/datatables.buttons.min.js',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/datatables.bootstrap4.min.js',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/buttons.bootstrap.min.js',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/dataTables.select.min.js',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/datatables.checkboxes.min.js',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/vendors/js/charts/apexcharts.min.js',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/js/core/app-menu.min.js',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/js/core/app.min.js',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/js/scripts/components.min.js',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/js/scripts/footer.min.js',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/js/scripts/extensions/toastr.min.js',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/vendors/js/extensions/toastr.min.js',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/js/scripts/ui/data-list-view.min.js',
    'node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js',
], 'public/js/app.js')
    
.styles([
    'resources/vuexy-assets/vendors/css/vendors-rtl.min.css',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/css-rtl/bootstrap.min.css',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/css-rtl/bootstrap-extended.min.css',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/css-rtl/pages/data-list-view.min.css',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/css-rtl/components.min.css',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/css-rtl/themes/semi-dark-layout.min.css',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/css-rtl/core/menu/menu-types/vertical-menu.min.css',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/css-rtl/custom-rtl.min.css',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/css-rtl/plugins/extensions/toastr.min.css',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/css-rtl/pages/app-chat.min.css',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/vendors/css/tables/datatable/datatables.min.css',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/css-rtl/colors.min.css',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/vendors/css/extensions/toastr.css',
    'resources/vuexy-assets/vendors/css/charts/apexcharts.css',
    'resources/css/videojs.css',
], 'public/css/app.css');
```

The Webpack processed `resources/js/app.js` into `public/tmp/app.js` and then converted all my JS files into one file without extra changes on other JS files. Also, for CSS files, it combined all CSS files into one file. Now I want to convert this to vite config file to do that.

Comment: What might be helpful is showing your Vite config and explaining what it's doing differently than you expect. I think what you want to do is have your own file in `resources/css` and `resources/js` subdirectory that imports the files you want, instead of listing them all in the packager manifest? But your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

To migrate from Laravel Mix to Vite, you need to follow these steps:

1. Install Vite and the Laravel Vite plugin as dev dependencies in your project:

```bash
npm install --save-dev vite laravel-vite-plugin
```

2. Create a `vite.config.js` file in your project root:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
    ],
});
```

3. Update your `package.json` scripts:

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "vite",
  "build": "vite build",
  "serve": "vite preview"
}
```

4. Remove the use of Laravl Mix's `@mix()` tags in your layouts and instead use `@vite` to reference your assets:

```
@vite(['resources/css/app.css'])
@vite(['resources/js/app.js'])
```

5. Run the build command:

```bash
npm run build
```

This will create a `dist` directory with your built assets.

Please note that Vite does not support combining multiple JS or CSS files into one file like Laravel Mix does. You will need to import your JS and CSS files in your `app.js` file or in your Vue components. Also, you have to convert any existing JavaScript `require` statements to `import`.

For example, in your `app.js` file:

```js
import 'resources/vuexy-assets/vendors/js/extensions/dropzone.min.js'
import 'resources/vuexy-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/datatables.min.js'
// import other JS files...

import 'resources/vuexy-assets/vendors/css/vendors-rtl.min.css'
import 'resources/vuexy-assets/css-rtl/bootstrap.min.css'
// import other CSS files...
```

6. Finally, you can delete your `webpack.mix.js` file and also remove Laravel Mix:

```
npm remove laravel-mix
```

Also, note that Vite has a different way of handling assets. You might need to adjust your asset paths or move your assets to the `public` directory. Check the [Vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. are you sure there is no way to combine the assets? I cannot import them in app.js because it will render them and codes will be with error.
now i'm using mix beside vite for that files.

Comment: @Sadegh What's the error?